# Convergence of sequence of functions on Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Let $\{f_{\alpha_n}\}\subset{\cal L}_2^0(\mathbb R)$ be a sequence function converging to $g$ where ${\cal L}_2^0(\mathbb R)$ is a Banach space defined by
$$
{\cal L}_2^0(\mathbb R)=\left\{h:\int_{\mathbb R}h=0\textrm{ and } \int_\mathbb Rh^2<\infty\right\}
$$
with norm $\|h\|=\left(\int_\mathbb Rh^2\right)^{\frac12}.$

Now, suppose that I am given $\{\alpha_n\}$ is a sequence of function in ${\cal C}^2$ converging to $\alpha_0$.

I wish to have $f_{\alpha_0}=g.$ Is it correct? I have this conjecture due to the uniqueness of limit, i.e., since $\{f_{\alpha_n}\}\to f_{\alpha_0}$. However, I haven't a clue to prove analytically. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not $f_n$ rather than ${{f}_{{{\alpha }_{n}}}}$? What does the $\alpha$ do? Why, further on, is f indexed by a sequence of functions ${\alpha}_n$?

Comment: How is $\int h $ defined if $ h $ isn't $ L^1$? For example, $$\int\limits_a^b \frac {x}{1+x^2} dx $$ will have different limits for different sequences $ a_i \to -\infty$ and $ b_i \to \infty $.

Comment: If you were on a bounded domain then you could use Poincare's Inequality.

Comment: @Paul: I wrote like that because $f_n$ is determined by $\alpha_n$

Comment: @user56535: I only consider all function $h$ such that $\int h=0$

Comment: @Jlamprong: The problem is that the integral is only well defined for $ L^1$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the extra conditions to your problem are unnecessary, and what you are essentially asking is if the $ L^2$ limit is the same as the $ C^2$ limit.

I claim they are the same for a $ C^0$ limit. To do so you only need to show that their $ L^2 $ difference is 0 on any compact set $ K $. Compare this $ L^2$ difference to the $ L^2$ differences between each limit and the sequence. Then use that $ K $ is compact to get that the terms coming from $ C^0$ limit approach 0. The $ L^2$ convergence will give you that the other terms approach 0.

So you get that the limits are the same for any compact set. Hence they are equal.

Comment: I'll try to apply your advice. Thanks a lot